# Typescript: Override global type of history

Tags: typescript

My typescript package contains a global type file that defines the `history` object like this:

lib.dom.d.ts

```
interface History {
    readonly length: number;
    scrollRestoration: ScrollRestoration;
    readonly state: any;
    back(): void;
    forward(): void;
    go(delta?: number): void;
    pushState(data: any, unused: string, url?: string | URL | null): void;
    replaceState(data: any, unused: string, url?: string | URL | null): void;
}

declare var history: History;
```

I'd like to tell the compiler that the `state` property has a `key` property.

I tried this:

```
declare global {
  interface TypedHistory extends History {
    state: { key: string };
  }
  var history: TypedHistory;
}

console.log(history.state.key);
```

But I'm getting this error:
`Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'history' must be of type 'History', but here has type 'TypedHistory'.`

How would I accomplish this? Preferably by declaring it in the same file I'm using the `history` object.

I'm not concerned whether or not this type definition always holds true, just how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had to move the var declaration outside the brackets. oops...

```
declare global {
  interface TypedHistory extends History {
    state: { key: string };
  }
}

declare var history: TypedHistory;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to overwrite the type of `history` in one place only, you can cast to a new type.

```js
const myHistory = (history as unknown) as TypedHistory
console.log(myHistory.state.key) // works
console.log(myHistory.state.otherKey) // will show TypeScript error
```

However, due to the type of `state` currently being `any`, you should already be able to access `history.state.key` without any TypeScript errors. The only thing you would be missing in this case is that you would not get errors when trying to access other properties that might not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was more concerned with not making dumb typos lol. `any` tends to burn you like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use interface merging

```
declare global {
  interface History {
    key: 123
  }
}

history.key // 123
```